# TexStudio crashes on the first run with texlive

Tags: texlive, texstudio, moderncv, linux

I installed `texlive` following the instructions given in the official [quick install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

I added the path and run `latex small2e` and everything works fine.

Then I installed `texstudio` via the aptitude.

When I opened my `moderncv.tex` file in texstudio and tried to compile it, I received the following error:

> Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT 1:** just in case you require information about my OS

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rosa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

**EDIT 2:** Answering the questions from the comment below

*Are you sure texmaker can find texlive?*

No. How can I make sure this? Plus, I don't use texmaker, I use texstudio.

*How was tex live installed?*

The internet method: donwloaded the tarball and ran `./install-tl`

*Did you add tex live to the path via .bashrc?*

I added it to `.bash_profile`, but not `.bashrc`. Why should I add it to `.bashrc`

Comment: Are you sure texmaker can find texlive? How was tex live installed? Did you add tex live to the path via `.bashrc`? Because that will not work if you then start texmaker from a menu, it should be added to `.profile`

Comment: i added answers for your questions

Comment: Sorry, misread, doesn't matter though. `.bash_profile` is still wrong. The addition to path will never get picked up by texstudio, unless perhaps if it was started from the command line. Add the path addition to `~/.profile`, log out and in again and see if that doesn't work. The shell used by programmes like texmaker or texstudio is not bash so bashrc or bash_profile is never executed and thus the path addition is ignored. Thus is a very common mistake on Linux

Comment: @daleif it worked! Please submit your suggestion as a question so I can accept it :)

Comment: Added my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a common error on Linux systems. Various places on the Internet lists that one should add to the path in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. That is not true, add it into `~/.profile` log out and in again. (Note, there are also system equivalents of these if you have a multi user system.)

Then reasoning is the following: when you start your editor from say a menu or by double clicking a file, the editor runs with whatever path settings was available at login. If you add the path change through bash, that addition is only available within bash contexts.

Whenever the editor calls latex as a system call it is very unlikely that it is using a bash shell, or even a call to a shell. Thus the editor is never affected by the path addition setup through bash.

By adding it to `~/.profile` we make sure that the path addition is added to the global stuff executed at login, and this the addition **is** available for the editor.